# Find duplicates in dataframe where one column can be within a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got everything figured out as far as finding duplicates.  I have a column marking them True or False and then I'm deleting one with a certain value.
At this point I just need to include anything where one column is within a range of rows.

For an example:

```
       Status Height Object  Store
0        Here   100'    ABC  EFG
1  Maybe here    99'    ABC  EFG
2  Maybe here   102'    ABC  JKL
3  Maybe here    99'    ABC  QRS
4        Here    80'    XYZ  QRS
5  Maybe here    78'    XYZ  JKL
```

Desired output:

```
       Status Height Object  Store
0        Here   100'    ABC  EFG
2  Maybe here   102'    ABC  JKL
3  Maybe here    99'    ABC  QRS
4        Here    80'    XYZ  QRS
5  Maybe here    78'    XYZ  JKL
```

The "Maybe here" rows should be deleted because their height is within +/- 4ft.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: You just want to remove rows where `Status` equal to `Maybe here`?

Comment: post your expected output df

Comment: With respect to which columns are you looking for duplicates? It seems to me that it's the `Object` one isn't it?
Then I guess the problem can became computational expensive cos for every values you want to delete `Height` values that are in the range +/- 4ft. But in this case if you have 80, 77, 74, 60 for the same object which one are you going to keep? 80,74, 60 or 77,60?

Comment: I'm looking for duplicates in 3 columns.  Height within 4 and object & store are the same.  I thought it would be expensive because of how many comparisons it has to make.  I've been manually removing the offending rows, which takes less time than the original method, but I wanted to see if I could get it 100% right every time.  I'm going to keep the ones that are "Here" as that means they definitely should not be deleted.  The "Maybe here" will be deleted if they are duplicates within 4 feet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy solution with specify values for get +-4 range and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
       Status Height Object
0        Here   100'    ABC
1  Maybe here    99'    ABC
2  Maybe here   102'    ABC
3  Maybe here    99'    ABC
4        Here    80'    XYZ
5  Maybe here    78'    XYZ


#specify values for check ranges
vals = [100, 80]
#remove traling 'and convert to integer
a = df['Height'].str.strip("'").astype(int)

#convert to numpy array and compare, get abs values
arr =  np.abs(np.array(vals) - a.values[:, None])
print (arr)
[[ 0 20]
 [ 1 19]
 [ 2 22]
 [ 1 19]
 [20  0]
 [22  2]]
```

---

```
#xreate boolean mask for match at least one True
mask = np.any((arr > 0) & (arr < 4), axis=1)
print (mask)
[False  True  True  True False  True]

#inverting condition by ~
print (df[~mask])
  Status Height Object
0   Here   100'    ABC
4   Here    80'    XYZ
```

Similar:

```
#invert conditions and check if all values Trues per row
mask = np.all((arr <= 0) | (arr >= 4), axis=1)
print (mask)
[ True False False False  True False]

print (df[mask])
  Status Height Object
0   Here   100'    ABC
4   Here    80'    XYZ
```

EDIT:

Solution is similar only chained new boolean mask created by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
#specify values for check ranges
vals = [100, 80]
#remove traling 'and convert to integer
a = df['Height'].str.strip("'").astype(int)

#convert to numpy array and compare, get abs values
arr =  np.abs(np.array(vals) - a.values[:, None])
print (arr)
[[ 0 20]
 [ 1 19]
 [ 2 22]
 [ 1 19]
 [20  0]
 [22  2]]
```

---

```
#create boolean mask for match at least one True
mask1 = np.any((arr > 0) & (arr < 4), axis=1)
print (mask1)
[False  True  True  True False  True]

mask2 = df.duplicated(subset=['Object','Store'], keep=False)
print (mask2)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool


mask = mask1 & mask2

#inverting condition by ~
print (df[~mask])
       Status Height Object Store
0        Here   100'    ABC   EFG
2  Maybe here   102'    ABC   JKL
3  Maybe here    99'    ABC   QRS
4        Here    80'    XYZ   QRS
5  Maybe here    78'    XYZ   JKL
```

---

```
#invert conditions and check if all values Trues per row
mask3 = np.all((arr <= 0) | (arr >= 4), axis=1)
print (mask3)
[ True False False False  True False]

mask = mask3 | ~mask2

print (df[mask])
       Status Height Object Store
0        Here   100'    ABC   EFG
2  Maybe here   102'    ABC   JKL
3  Maybe here    99'    ABC   QRS
4        Here    80'    XYZ   QRS
5  Maybe here    78'    XYZ   JKL
```

Comment: This is really close, but it deletes some rows that it shouldn't.  I mistakenly left out another column that I'm taking into consideration.  If the store and object are the same and they are within 4ft, then they should be deleted.  This method deleted 4 rows where 3 had the same store, all objects were unique, and the heights were 270, 269, 268, 268

Comment: @jezrael, pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250164/convert-outline-format-in-csv-to-two-columns

Answer (score 1):

To decide whether to delete a row based on `height`, check if at least one element in `[height-threshold, height+threshold]` is already present in the `dictionary`. If present, remove the `height`

For example, if `height=80` & `threshold=4`, check if at least one number among `76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84` is present in the `dictionary`. If present, delete the row.

```
global dictionary

def can_i_remove(item, threshold):
    global dictionary
    key = item-threshold
    while(key <= (item+threshold)):
        if(dictionary.get(key) != None):
            return True
        key = key+1
    dictionary[item] = False
    return False

def main():
    global dictionary
    dictionary = dict()
    threshold = 4
    ret = can_i_remove(100, threshold)
    print(str(dictionary) + " -> 100 - " + str(ret))
    ret = can_i_remove(96, threshold)
    print(str(dictionary) + " -> 96 - " + str(ret))
    ret = can_i_remove(95, threshold)
    print(str(dictionary) + " -> 95 - " + str(ret))
    ret = can_i_remove(104, threshold)
    print(str(dictionary) + " -> 104 - " + str(ret))
    ret = can_i_remove(105, threshold)
    print(str(dictionary) + " -> 105 - " + str(ret))

main()
```

Output :

```
{100: False} -> 100 - False
{100: False} -> 96 - True
{100: False, 95: False} -> 95 - False
{100: False, 95: False} -> 104 - True
{100: False, 95: False, 105: False} -> 105 - False
```