# Convert Outline format in CSV to Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a CSV file of the following format (one column in a `dataframe`). This is essentially like an outline in a Word document, where the headers I've shown here are letters are the main headers, and the items as numbers are subheaders:

- A
- 1
- 2
- 3
- B
- 1
- 2
- C
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

I want to convert this to the following format (two columns in a `dataframe`):

- A 1
- A 2
- A 3
- B 1
- B 2
- C 1
- C 2
- C 3
- C 4

I'm using `pandas` `read_csv` to convert the data into a `dataframe`, and I'm trying to reformat through for loops, but I'm having difficulty because the data repeats and gets overwritten. For example, `A 3` will get overwritten with `C 3` (resulting in two instance of `C 3` when only one is desired, and losing `A 3` altogether) later in the loop. What's the best way to do this?

Apologies for poor formatting, new to the site.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#if no csv header use names parameter
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['col'])

df.insert(0, 'a', df['col'].mask(df['col'].str.isnumeric()).ffill())

df = df[df['a'] != df['col']]
print (df)
    a col
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   A   3
5   B   1
6   B   2
8   C   1
9   C   2
10  C   3
11  C   4
```

**Details**:

Check [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) values:

```
print (df['col'].str.isnumeric())
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Replace `True` by `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and forward fill missing values:

```
print (df['col'].mask(df['col'].str.isnumeric()).ffill())
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     B
7     C
8     C
9     C
10    C
11    C
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Add new column to first position by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'a', df['col'].mask(df['col'].str.isnumeric()).ffill())
print (df)
    a col
0   A   A
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   A   3
4   B   B
5   B   1
6   B   2
7   C   C
8   C   1
9   C   2
10  C   3
11  C   4
```

and last remove rows with same values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).